# UITableView doesn't display UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have set up the following Screen in `InterfaceBuilder`:

[image]

Connected `IBOutlets` and required functions to conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols. Not much functionality yet - just the structure to start with.
Here's the ViewController's Code:

```swift
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var AllCoopsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var RecentCoopsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var LatestNotificationsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var OpenCoops: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CompletedCoops: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Earnings: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var OpenCoopsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CompletedCoopsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var EarningsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ShowAllCoopsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ShowAllNotificationsButton: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var RecentCoopsTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var LatestNotificationsTable: UITableView!
    let apiService = APIService()
    var parentController: TabBarController?
    var user: User?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        RecentCoopsTable.dataSource = self
        RecentCoopsTable.delegate = self
        LatestNotificationsTable.dataSource = self
        LatestNotificationsTable.delegate = self

        let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authtoken")!
        self.apiService.getUserFromAuthtoken(token: token, completion: {result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let user):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.user = user
                    self.parentController = self.tabBarController as? TabBarController
                    self.parentController?.user = user
                    Globals.shared.user = user
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("An error occured \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("Was here")
        let coopCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecentCoopsViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CoopViewCell
        coopCell.CoopName.text = "foo bar"
        return coopCell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }



    @IBAction func showAllCooperationsButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("showAllCooperationsButtonPressed")
    }



    @IBAction func showAllNotificationsButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("showAllNotificationsButtonPressed")
    }
}



class CoopViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var CoopName: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}



class NotificationViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

The way I see it, I should see 3 table rows saying "foo bar". 
But I don't. Just get this.

[image]

Also not getting the 3 expected "Was here" console logs.
What have I missed?

Comment: Is it possible you forgot to set the class of your view controller in Storyboard to `HomeViewController`? Put a `print("home view did load")` statement in `viewDidLoad()` to confirm the class is actually connected.

Comment: have you tried to reload the tableview?

Comment: I was going to post my answer but @Harish answered. You should reload the table view when you add new data. Use ```YOUR_TALBE_VIEW.reloadData()```. For more detail check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata

Comment: I've added as answer! Hope you accept it!

Comment: Check your cell identifier and cell class name which is you are passing in cellForRowindexPath.

Comment: @DonMag: Thanks, but the HomeWievController was connected. Print statement gets executed. But TableViewCells still not showing.

Comment: @VipinPareek: Verified before and just double checked now. Class and Identifier I'm using in cellForRowindexPath match with what has been set in the Interface Builder.

Comment: @ ALL: find it weird that the "Was here" print statement in `cellForRowAt` doesn't get executed at all. As there's a hard-coded "return 3" in `numberOfRowsInSection`, it should at least run that print statement 3 times, regardless of whatever else might be wrong in `cellForRowAt`. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Now added a fixed height constraint to the table view and it finally executes `cellForrowAt`. Now getting the following error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier RecentCoopsViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard` - I've triple checked the Identifier and it's set correctly in the InterfaceBuilder. No clue what's going wrong here...

Comment: check your cell class you assign. i think you din't assign your table cell class that's why that error appears if everything set then set your delegate and datasource from storyboard also because sometime they not work and in your case the table view delegate and data source not working.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata)

Try to reload the tableView after the API call.

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Sorry for including the API call in the first place. It doesn't load any data that I'm showing in the tableView (yet). Should have left it out in order to not confuse anyone. At this point (with the code I shared) the only thing that should show up in the table view are 3 hard coded "foo bars". However, I've added a reload statement now - just to verify that it would indeed not have any effect. And it didn't...

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that I didn't handle the second table view in cellforRowAt
The following fixed it:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("Was here")
        if(tableView == RecentCoopsTable) {
            let coopCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecentCoopsViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CoopViewCell
            coopCell.CoopName.text = "foo bar"
            return coopCell
        } else if(tableView == LatestNotificationsTable) {
            let coopCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LatestNotificationsViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NotificationViewCell
            return coopCell
        }
        else {return UITableViewCell()}
    }
```

Still having fixed height of tableViews in IB, which is not ideal.
If anyone has a solution for that, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have assigned a cell identifier and class to the storyboard. This should help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This view controller has 2 table view cells and both have set same view controller as its delegate. Hence `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` methods must be called for both the table views. And hence it must print `"Was here"` total 6 times, 3 times for each table view. As this is not printed the main suspect seems the view controller's class is not set as `HomeViewController`. Will you please try adding a print statement in `viewDidLoad` method?

Also the forced unwrapping of cell to in `cellForRowAt` should crash on the first cell of notification table view.